# Linq To Entities - How to create a query where the table name is a parameter

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic-sql, dynamic-linq

Dynamic queries are not dynamic enough. I have seen solutions like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) but still I have to indicate which table to use as the basis:

```
var query = db.Customers.Where("...").OrderBy("...").Select("...");
```

I want to create a simple query tool where the user will select from available tables using a drop-down list. As the result, I want to show first few records. Therefore, **I need to change the table** too! That is, I need something like this:

```
string selectedTable = "Customers";
var [tableName] = SomeTypecastingOperations(selectedTable);
var query = db.[tableName].Where("...").OrderBy("...").Select("...");
```

Is EF **dynamic** enough to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq-to-entities doesn't support that. You can achieve that with [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx) or some ugly code which will have conditional logic for every set you want to query (like a big `switch` for table names).

Comment: I am curious about your _big switch_ solution. One side will be my  `selectedTable` but the other side does not have a polymorphic superclass :(
I can write a code generator for this switch, however I cannot return different results like `ObjectSet<Customer>` or `ObjectSet<Product>`, etc.

Comment: That switch will not return anything. It will directly fill your UI.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean with **ugly** :-)